# How to get data from relation's with data stored in array's of Id

Tags: mongodb, foreign-keys, relationship, loopback

I have a model batches which has data as

```
"id": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": true,
      "defaultFn": "uuidv4"
    },
    "batchType": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "default": "COURSE"
    },
    "venue": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
```

and another Model say bookedBathes

```
"batchesId": {
     "type": [
       "string"
     ],
     "required": true
   },
```

and created a relations from batches model to bookedBatches model as

```
 "relations": {
    "bookedBatches": {
      "type": "referencesMany",
      "model": "bookedBatches",
      "foreignKey": "batchesId",
      "primaryKey": "id"
    }
  }
```

now I want all the batches with booked details that are stored as array's of Id in booked details from batch model

```
let reqObject = {
                    "where": {
                        "and": [{
                            userId: userId,
                            isActive: true
                        }]
                    },
                    "order": "createdAt DESC",
                    include: [
                        {{
                            relation:"bookedBatches"}}]
}


Batches.find(reqObject, (resError, resData) => {
                    if (resError) {
                        return cb(new HttpErrors.BadRequest(resError, {
                            expose: false
                        }))
                    }
                    return cb(null, resData);
                })
```

But I am not getting any value can any one help to get the values through relation's

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

i have improved your code. Please try this

```
 let reqObject = {
  "where": {
    "and": [{
      userId: userId,
      isActive: true
    }]
  },
  "order": "createdAt DESC",
  include: [
    {
      relation: "bookedBatches",
      scope: { fields: ["id","batchesId"] }
    }
  ]
}


Batches.find(reqObject, (resError, resData) => {
  if (resError) {
    return cb(new HttpErrors.BadRequest(resError, {
      expose: false
    }))
  }
  return cb(null, resData);
})
```